# Creating Dynamic List From Table [Excel 365]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a dynamic list of employees based on a department drop-down.

Basically, when I change the dropdown from dept to dept, I need the sheet to auto-populate a listing of employees within that department.

I have the dropdown created with the appropriate department values.

My reference table contains a list of all employees with columns First Name, Last Name, Employee Type and Department. The departments are an exact match between my table and my dropdown options.

I believe because this is a 2-dimensional action I need to use arrays or sub-arrays to get my data, but I've never used them and I've had no luck in experimenting.

My source table is in a separate worksheet named "Source" and my dynamic list is in a worksheet named "Listing"

I've tried google (obv) 
I have tried an Index-Match, but that appears to be too limited to return multiple entries
I have tried (and failed) to use an array. This was almost certainly user error.

Expected result: Change department dropdown and a list of employees (first name, last name, employee type) is populated. This list can vary from 1 employee in that department to over 50

Answer (score 0):

An easy work-around is to assign each employee with a unique number and then use the MAXIFS / MINIFS formulas.

To populate the list (here assuming you choose the MINIFS formula) you need to make two different formulas.

For the first person, you find the employee with the lowest number within the department:

```
=MINIFS([employee number column], [department column], [department dropdown])
```

You then lookup the employee name using the employee number.

For the second employee and onward you add the condition that the employee number must be greater than the one above:

```
 =MINIFS([employee number column], [department column], [department dropdown], [employee number column], ">"&[the cell above])
```

You copy this formula down as far as you need. Again you lookup the employee name using the employee number.

To handle errors (eg. when there are no more employees), add an IFERROR and set it to "" to only show names.